# How to remove side axis numbers

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am working on a very generic function graphing program using Zedgraph.

[image: The program]

I was wondering, is there a built-in Boolean or a method to remove the numbers on the side so that it looks something like this:

[image: The final product expectation]

Comment: You should use this site for concise problems, post some code, make others understand your context and your problem.

Comment: The pictures are a bit large but his question and problem description are just right. What code could one post while he is looking for the one boolean that will do the trick??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played around with a number of option and could not find one which would remove the axis numbers which is in fact what most graphs are for.  But you could get the code as its open source and modify it your self.